# Do system dsn requires administrative rights

Tags: sql, odbc, system, user-permissions, dsn

I have developed application which uses Sytem DSN (odbc driver 32 bit). Whenever I try to establish connection with database I have to run it exe and  I have to use "Run as administrator". Is it compulsory to have admin rights to use SYSTEM DSN or there any way any user can run even if they don't have administrator rights.